# Stanford CoreNLP train model from text file like englishPCFG.ser.gz

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, language-packs

I am new to Stanford CoreNLP, Initially I have worked with Moses project.
So far I have worked with the demo file ParserDemo2 and everything worked fine using englishPCFG.caseless.ser.gz model.
I need to create my own model, from the text English monolingual corpus which I have.

So far I have searched and found that I need to create a TreeBank and use method trainFromTreebank in LexicalizedParser class.

I am really confused how to do this.

Can you provide some information or point me to the documentation on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The Stanford Parser FAQ answers: ["Can I train the parser?"](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#d)

It's probably easiest to start with a vanilla PCFG model and then work your way up with state-splitting, etc. to more complex models. See ["Can I just use the parser as a vanilla PCFG parser?"](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#p)

Comment: I am confused about how to make to normal monolingual corpus into Penn Treebank format
I went to  
https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/ but didn’t find anything useful.

Comment: What does "monolingual corpus" mean? What does the data look like? It needs to have constituency parse annotations of some sort in place already.

Comment: All I have is a large corpus of English sentences, using which I need to train the model.

Comment: You need labeled data to build a parser with Stanford models or otherwise — i.e., examples of how sentences are parsed. That means your data must come with tree annotations, in the Penn Treebank format or a similar format.

Comment: Can you point me to any link on how to convert it to Penn Treebank. I am not able to find it through google search.

Comment: The data needs to be manually annotated with parse annotations. You can't build a good parser for the text otherwise.